# Multiple jQuery scripts used - how include these in an extendable OO way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Are there any docs or training materials available that advise the best way to include multiple jQuery plugins in an abstract way, allowing for extension of those plugins, and also global control of things like events, setTimeout() etc?

I want to be able to do these kind of things:

- Extend someone else's jQuery plugin, e.g. if I want to add a new feature, but not touch the original codebase
- Have my own server-side detection script pass a value to JS (using a HTML meta tag) so JS can detect that and then decide which script to use (e.g. tone down some of the jQuery for lesser devices)
- Better control all the events that are attached
- setTimeout() - I have loads of these dotted around the place at various intervals - I want to control all this in one function
- Add my own fixes to jQuery scripts. If I download a ready-made one and use it I always find I can improve usability - especially on mobile devices - so I want to add my own fixes and improvements.
- Control the resize event. There's all sorts going on at the moment and it's quite a job triggering a full re-size when I write new code (and the resize is pretty slow on some mobile devices)

Comment: You should better ask multiple questions instead of putting this all into one.

Comment: Can you revise the question to be more terse?

Comment: Thanks, I've re-worded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or similar library to load scripts dynamically depending on screen size or navigator's user agent parameter (You will need to set condition checking yourself though).